# Forcefully forget / unmount ZFS pool after drives disconnected

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux, openzfs

First off, I made a mistake & I acknowledge that, but now I'm stuck with a "broken" ZFS driver and want to restore it without rebooting my machine.

How I can say ZFS on Linux to just forget the existence of a pool (forcefully unmount & "export" it) while all drives are disconnected?

While I had a running ZFS pool with two drives (as mirror), I disconnected both of them (more specific: their power) at the same time without unmounting or exporting it beforehand. When replugging the power, the kernel recognized them as new drives (before they were called sdb & sdc, now they are called sdd & sde) hence ZFS is not able to "restart" the pool on its own. I do not want to call commands like `zpool replace` as they seem to expect that the new drive is completely new & and can be overwritten, what is not the case (in fact, they are the same, just available under a new name/path). I tried some other commands (see below), but they didn't worked as well. So I disconnected them again but now I'm stuck with a ZFS driver not being able to forcefully unmount the pool, so I could just trying to reimport it. As during the power fail no writes should have happened, I just expect to be able to reimport it afterwards just fine.

What I tried so far while the drives were connected under the new name:

- `zpool offline pool1 sdb`: "cannot offline sdb: pool I/O is currently suspended"
- `zpool online pool1 sdd`: "cannot online /dev/sdd: pool I/O is currently suspended"

What I tried while the drives were disconnected:

- `zpool clear pool1`
- `zpool export -f pool1`
- `zpool destroy -f pool1`

Just in case its important: Debian GNU/Linux bookworm, Linux 6.1.0-6-amd64

Answer (score 0):

While writing this exhaustive error description, I got it back up running by re-connecting the drives in the correct order because Linux new decided to use their old names again (so ZFS can find them at the same path), ran `zfs clear pool1` and they were up again.

If you connect them in the wrong order (e.g. old sdc shows now up as sdb), after running `clear`, ZFS will show a `CORRUPTED` error. If that is so, I was able to just disconnect the drive, connect the other one (so the correct one shows up as sdb again), and ZFS recognized the first drive after `zpool clear` again. The second drive was then recognized immediately on reconnecting it.

I decided to still post this as my Google foo didn't brought up any solution working for me and because one question is still open to me: Is it possible to "restart" the pool with the different drive names or do I have to have luck that the kernel will give them the same names again (please answer in a comment or another answer)?